# Basic JS Youtube subscriber count not working with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm having an odd problem with using the Youtube API v3 in jQuery. Though full of documentation, I couldn't find a fast and simple way to grab the subscriber count, eventually I ran across one and it works great in a project here; http://codepen.io/Sepshun/pen/bgOgzE (starting at line 33)

```
// Create a script element to execute the API URL
var getsubs = document.createElement("script");
getsubs.src = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id='+channelID+'&key=AIzaSyAyWsBUsAChiYPDOptU-NBAh_p7oExR1oc&callback=getJSON';
document.head.appendChild(getsubs);

// Get Youtube JSON response
function getJSON(response) {
    var subCount = response.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount;

    // Update YT Count Text
    $("#yt-count").text(roundNum(subCount));
}
```

However, when reconstructing this code with jQuery to work on multiple accounts across a table, the youtube portion doesn't work; http://codepen.io/Sepshun/pen/apXqKO?editors=0011 (line 29)

To try and sum it up, I'm defining a variable which when used will create a script element, I then set the source of that variable to be the link to Youtube API based on what channel ID is currently in place, using &callback=getJSON, when the script loads it should call the getJSON function, from there, the subscriber count is saved as a variable and then wrote to a DOM element, this is being initialized by appending the getsubs variable to the head. This works flawlessly in the first pen linked, but in the second pen the script element gets added to the head, but isn't calling the getJSON function.

I tried searching for a similar problem but it seems this is a bit too specific to find answers elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I solved the problem with a pastebin bit I found elsewhere:

```
http://pastebin.com/vUaxpHWJ
http://codepen.io/Sepshun/pen/xgMQBP?editors=0011
```